# iphone memset issue

Tags: iphone, memset

I defined a struct in my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    
typedef struct ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA_tag
{
    byte    exch;          
    byte    complex_stat;                   
    char    contract[8];    
    byte    status;         
    byte    type;        
}ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA;
@interface NetTestAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    CFSocketRef _socket;
    CFDataRef address;
    ORIGINAL_QUOTA_DATA oQuota;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
```

in my .m file:

```
    static void TCPServerConnectCallBack(CFSocketRef socket, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info){
memset(&oQuota, 0, sizeof(oQuota));
}
```

but it gets worning:
[image]

Comment: We need context: where is the line ? Is this inside a method of `NetTestAppDelegate` ? Is it inside a C function ?

Comment: How do you want to set that value with zeros in `static` method when this variable is not `static`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing `oQuota` from C function (it's also static but that's not the problem). Your `oQuota` variable is only "in scope" inside Objective-C methods implementation for your `NetTestAppDelegate`:

```
void myCFunction()
{
    // oQuota cannot be referenced here.
}

@implementation NetTestAppDelegate
- (void)myObjectiveCMethod
{
   // oQuota is in scope, can reference it.
}
@end
```

But what you *can* do is pass the object to your callback:

```
static void TCPServerConnectCallBack(CFSocketRef socket, CFSocketCallBackType type, CFDataRef address, const void *data, void *info){
    memset(
      &((NetTestAppDelegate *)info)->oQuota,
      0,
      sizeof(((NetTestAppDelegate *)info)->oQuota)
    );
    // Not sure whether the sizeof works, try it.
}
```

In your `CFSocketContext`, you then need to set:

```
myCFSocketContext.info = self;
```